# Fixing Incorrect String Encoding From MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, unicode, character-encoding

I'm reading strings from a mysql database which isn't set up for Unicode.

Ruby gets the string as `ä¸ƒå¤§æ´‹` but I know the correct version should be `七大洋`. The "wrong" string is encoded as UTF-8 because Ruby doesn't know it has it wrong. I've tried forcing every encoding on the mangled string but nothing works. I have a feeling that I might be able to do it by fiddling with the bits but I don't even know where to start.

I don't think any information has been lost because the incorrect string actually has *more* bytes than the correct one. I don't think Ruby is the culprit here because the strings also look mangled when I view the table outside Ruby - so I'm hoping to undo the damage that MySQL has already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following construction to revert encoding:

```
"wrong_string".encode(Encoding::SOME_ENCODING).force_encoding('utf-8')
```

I tried all possible encodings to detect right encoding:

```
Encoding.constants.each_with_object({}) do |encoding_name, result|
  value = "ä¸ƒå¤§æ´‹".encode(Encoding.const_get encoding_name).force_encoding('utf-8') rescue nil
  result[encoding_name] = value if value == "七大洋"
end.keys
#=> [:Windows_1252, :WINDOWS_1252, :CP1252, :Windows_1254, :WINDOWS_1254, :CP1254]
```

Thus, to convert your string to `七大洋` you can use any encoding from above.

Comment: Use `Encoding.list` or `Encoding.name_list` instead of `Encoding.constants`.

Answer (score 2):

Alexander pointed out my main mistake (you need to `encode` then `force_encoding` to find the right encoding). The string is indeed encoded as CP1252!

The best solution is to read binary from MySQL and then force encoding:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(opts.merge encoding: 'binary')
# ...
text.force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

Or, if you can't change how you're getting the data, you'll be stuck with a `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError` when you try to `encode`. As detailed in [this blog post](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/12/07/solving-latin1-and-utf8-errors-for-good-in-ruby.html), the solution is to specify encodings for the [five undefined CP1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Code_page_layout) bytes:

```
fallback = {
  "\u0081" => "\x81".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u008D" => "\x8D".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u008F" => "\x8F".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u0090" => "\x90".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u009D" => "\x9D".force_encoding("CP1252")
}

text.encode('CP1252', fallback: fallback).force_encoding('UTF-8')
```