# In Ruby, how to UTF-8 encode this weird character?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I'm importing content from an outside database that is infected with a variety of odd characters, e.g.

```
> str
=> "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
```

From context it seems that *â€™* represents a right single-quote. In cp1252 encoding:

```
> str.encode('cp1252')
=> "Nature\xE2\x80\x99s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
```

So how do I convert it to the correct UTF-8 character? Here's what I've tried:

```
> str.encode('UTF-8')
=> "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"

> str.encode('cp1252').encode('UTF-8')
=> "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"

> str.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '?', undef: :replace)
=> "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"

> str.encode('cp1252').encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '?', undef: :replace)                                                                  
=> "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
```

I'd rather find a way to do a generic re-encoding so that it will handle all such miss-encoded characters. But if I have to I'll do individual search and replacing. But I'm not able to make that work either:

```
> str.encode('cp1252').gsub('\xE2/x80/x99', "'")
=> "Nature\xE2\x80\x99s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"

> str.encode('cp1252').gsub(%r{\xE2\x80\x99}, "'")
SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end

> str.encode('cp1252').gsub(Regexp.escape('\xE2\x80\x99'), "'")
=> "Nature\xE2\x80\x99s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
```

I'd like to do this, but I can't even paste these characters into my REPL:

```
> str.gsub('â€™', "'")
```

When I try I get:

```
> str.gsub('C"b,b,b
* "', ",")
=> "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
```

Frustrating. Any suggestions on how to encode this properly into UTF-8?

Edit: At the request for the actual bytes in the string:

```
> str.bytes.to_a.join(' ')
=> "78 97 116 117 114 101 195 162 226 130 172 226 132 162 115 32 86 97 114 105 101 116 121 44 32 66 101 115 116 32 70 114 105 101 110 100 115 32 65 110 105 109 97 108 32 83 111 99 105 101 116 121 32 116 101 97 109 32 117 112"
```

Comment: What is `str.encoding` when you have the `â€™` mess? What are the underlying bytes?

Comment: @muistooshort, `str.encoding # => #<Encoding UTF-8>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this problem with [Fixing Incorrect String Encoding From MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596786/fixing-incorrect-string-encoding-from-mysql). You need to set the proper encoding and then force it back.

```
fallback = {
  "\u0081" => "\x81".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u008D" => "\x8D".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u008F" => "\x8F".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u0090" => "\x90".force_encoding("CP1252"),
  "\u009D" => "\x9D".force_encoding("CP1252")
}

str.encode('CP1252', fallback: fallback).force_encoding('UTF-8')
```

The fallback may not be necessary depending on your data, but it ensures that it won't raise an error by handling the five bytes which are undefined in CP1252.

Comment: This is ridiculous that this is the solution to this problem, but it worked very well, so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Once Ruby has got the encoding wrong, the characters will stay incorrect, according to the original mistake. Conversions simply convert the now wrong characters into the new encoding.

To correct Ruby's mistake on input, you need to use the `force_encoding` method, which does not do a conversion, it just corrects Ruby's note of what encoding a `String` has.

In your case the fault has occurred *before* you read the values from the DB. If you pick out the problem bytes: `bytes = %w(195 162 226 130 172 226 132 162).map(&:to_i)` they look to be in UTF-8 encoding, and *already* in the database double-encoded. You can probably assume a problem with whatever has written these into the DB (note if it is a live process, this is a bug that needs sorting, you will continue to get these bad values in).

What has happened is your DB (or code that writes to it) received some UTF-8 bytes representing the correct character, but *assumed* they were CP1252 to be converted to UTF-8. It made that conversion and wrote valid UTF-8 (but wrong characters) into the DB.

If I do the following in Ruby console using UTF-8 encoding in my terminal and as the default Ruby encoding, I can replicate your problem:

```
str = "Nature’s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
 => "Nature’s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
str = str.force_encoding('CP1252').encode('UTF-8')
 => "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
```

The fault is reversible, as shown here:

```
str = str.encode('CP1252').force_encoding('UTF-8')
 => "Nature’s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"
```

The `encode('CP1252')` undoes the original mistaken conversion.

The `force_encoding('UTF-8')` sets the encoding back to what the system most likely received in the first place.

You will want to find where in your system an assumption of CP1252 input is being made, and instead assume UTF-8 (it may get more complicated than that if you have multiple sources in different encodings).

Comment: This fails for me. That exact line yields _ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)_. Changing `encoding` to `encode` yields a string with other weirdness: " "NatureÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"

Comment: Sorry I got the second method name wrong, corrected. Your original string is not in CP1252 encoding then. Can you give the original bytes, *before* any calls to `encode`?

Comment: The original bytes are at the top of the question: "Natureâ€™s Variety, Best Friends Animal Society team up"

Comment: @Mori: Those are not bytes - they are characters as interpreted by Ruby assuming whatever the default or input encoding is (which you do not give).  `str.bytes` will give the bytes. I need to see the bytes before I can guess the encoding in the DB. It is also possible you have some trouble upstream and the database entries already contain some mis-converted or double-encoded entries.

Comment: `str.bytes` yields an enumerator. How do I get actual bytes from that?

Comment: Old Ruby version. `str.bytes.to_a`

Comment: I've added the bytes to the question.